# Make Number Full-Length in f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to make this code, and I need to make the precent show the whole number in the f-string instead of it saying 9e-06% or something like that. (Python)

```
import random
x = random.randint(1, 1000000)
y = float(100000000)
precent = float(0)
while x != y:
  y = float(input('Number from 1 to 1000000: '))
  if x != y:
    print('Wrong, try again')
  precent = precent+0.000001
wow = f'Wow! That only had a {precent}% chance of happening!'
print(wow)
```

Comment: I think it's better to replace `precent = precent+0.000001` with `precent = "0.000001"`.

Comment: `f'Wow! That only had a {precent:f}% chance of happening!'`

Comment: Use format modifiers as in `{percent:9.7f}`.